# How can I restart swank in Leiningen's interactive mode?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Let's say I'm running Leiningen in interactive mode ('lein interactive') and have started a Swank Clojure server ('swank').  Now I want to kill/restart the Swank server without killing Leiningen as well.  How can I do this?  Is this even possible?

So far I've just been using Ctrl-C to kill both, which doesn't make Leiningen's interactive mode all that useful for me since I may as well have just ran 'lein swank' to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't implemented yet. However, the interactive task is intended for people who don't use swank. Swank already keeps a JVM open for your project, so that kind of defeats the purpose of the interactive task.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Slime, you can call `,rest` which is bound to `(restart-inferior-lisp)`. This will restart your swank session.

Comment: When I try this (using M-x clojure-jack-in), I get in the minibuffer: "No inferior lisp process".